# Tailwind > using has- in combination with &> child selector

Tags: tailwind-css

I have following HTML

```
<div className='has-[.true]:[&>*]:hidden px-1 py-2 text-sm border-t relative md:border-r'>
      <MenuToggle />
      <div
        id='menuContainer'
        className='flex flex-row items-center w-full h-full md:flex-col'
      >
```

Inside MenuToggle there is logic to add .true class and that works with the parent's has- selector. For instance, this works

```
has-[.true]:hidden
```

this will hide the parent. However, I do not wish to hide parent, but another child of parent, the one with id=menuContainer. So I tried to make child selector work, via [&>*], but I'm missing something.

something like this is what I am trying to do, but failing

```
has-[.true]:[&>#menuContainer]:hidden
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using peer, however, if it is possible to combine has with child selector, I would appreciate an example.

now I can directly hide the div I wish without parent. MenuToggle has a div inside with "peer" class mark.

```
<div className='px-1 py-2 text-sm border-t relative md:border-r'>
      <MenuToggle />
      <div className='peer-[.true]:hidden flex flex-row items-center w-full h-full md:flex-col'>
        <div className='hidden items-center mt-5 mb-10 md:flex'>
          <Logo className='size-7' />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is doing this by using a `useState()` so you don't have to use the `has-`.

You can do this :

```js
const [display, setDidplay] = useState(false);

<div
  className="px-1 py-2 text-sm border-t relative md:border-r"
>
  <div onClick={() => setDisplay(!display)}>icon here</div>
    { display ? (
        <div id="menuContainer" 
        className="flex flex-row items-center w-full h-full md:flex-col"></div>
    ) : null }
</div>
```

Comment: using has - is I believe a better choice, why use JavaScript when you can use CSS ? Addittionally, Im using NextJs and Menu can be a server component, with useState I'd have to make it "use client";

Comment: Of course, but it's easier to use a useState for visibility. You can still make your file 'use cleint' with using a server component in it.